# need to remove .pdf extension from filename array_map

Tags: php

I have the following code producing an array of filenames in a directory.

```
<?php
$filepathname= '../clients/Quote/'.date('ymd').'*';
$filesfound = array_map('basename', glob($filepathname));

print_r ($filesfound);
?>
```

This produces the Array ( [0] => 14060603.pdf [1] => 1406060301.pdf )

I want to remove the filename extension. .pdf. so that it instead produces the 
Array ( [0] => 14060603 [1] => 1406060301 )

Thank you for your help.

Furthermore as a second question how can I get the key in this array that has the highest value.

therefore [1] => 1406060301 would be selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that the files all end with `.pdf`, you may use the optional second parameter of [`basename`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php):

```
<?php
$filepathname= '../clients/Quote/'.date('ymd').'*';
$filesfound = glob($filepathname);
foreach($filesfound as $key => $val){
    $filesfound[$key] = basename($val, ".pdf");
}

print_r($filesfound);

$max = max(array_keys($filesfound));
print($max); // prints the key with the highest value
?>
```

Comment: Thank you I have no idea who voted me down or why my question was worth voting down, but thank you very much.